# How to put an image on the tab bar next to the title of the page on the browser?

Tags: image, html, jsp

Hi I am wondering how to put an image on the tab bar same as this website that has placed its logo on the left side of its title. as following picture.

[image]

Comment: Great I have the same question !!!! thanks for asking

Comment: The [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)?

Comment: Did you try to look at the source code? What does it look like? What did you try to get it to work? Remember you are expected to do some research before asking a question.

Comment: @DavidThomas don't waste rep and post your answer.

Comment: @Floris, I do not know what it is called so how to  research on it ?

Comment: I googled *web page icon* and it appears [Favicon - icon for webpage](http://www.rw-designer.com/favicon) in the first page of answers =\

Comment: Did you even _look_ at the source code? Your answer is the seventh line of this page. "Research" is not always the same thing as "type the keyword in Google". When you have a working sample like this you have a perfect opportunity to learn by doing. Too bad you didn't grab it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called a [`favicon`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) and it's set with a `<link>` tag in the document's `header` tag.

For example, Stack Overflow sets it with:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

The first tag is the cross browser way of setting the icon for common desktop browsers. The second tag is meant for iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're referring to is called a Favicon.  Here's a link that helps you make (or import an image) and then exports the favicon for you to use.  Once you've downloaded the file, just place it on the root of your site directory.

http://www.favicon.cc